# pdfLaTeX produces different outputs from the same file

Tags: pdftex, compiling, output

I am writing a report using LaTeX and I am quite confused about something. I am working with TeXShop, and the output produced after compiling sometimes changes.

Let me show some screenshots

- Here you cansee the desired output
  [image: normal text]
- But sometimes the output looks like this, with the strange font
  [image: anormal text]
- Same for formulas, the desired output is
  [image: normal formula]
- But sometimes it looks more like this
  [image: anormal formula]

It is crucial to note that the *.tex* source file is exactly the same for all the previous examples.

**How is it possible that pdfTeX produces different outputs? Have I done something wrong in the source file? Is it my TeX distribution that has issues or my computer?**

---

This is the preamble of my *.tex* file, just in case something obvious stands in it:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{report}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\numberwithin{equation}{chapter}
\usepackage{bbold}%necessaire pour le caractere 1 qui represente l'identite matricielle
\usepackage{tikz}

\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Part}}

\usepackage{titlesec}%modification de la gueule des sections,etc

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\Huge\normalfont\filcenter\scshape\bfseries\sffamily}
{\rule[0pt]{1cm}{1cm}\hfill\thechapter
%\vspace{1pt}
\hrule}
{-25pt}
{}
\titleformat{\section}[hang]
{\large\normalfont\scshape\bfseries}
{\thesection}
{1em}%10pt
{}
\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]
{\normalfont\scshape\bfseries}
{\thesubsection}
{1em}%5pt
{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}[runin]
{\normalsize\normalfont\scshape}
{}
{1em}
{\rule{5pt}{5pt}\quad}

\bibliographystyle{plain}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper}

%macros definition
\newcommand\com[2]{\left[#1,#2 \right]}
\newcommand\abs[1]{\left|#1 \right|}
\newcommand\mean[1]{\left\langle #1\right\rangle}
\newcommand\dd[2]{\frac{\mathrm{d}#1}{\mathrm{d}#2}}
\newcommand\ddd[2]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^2#1}{\mathrm{d}#2^2}}
\newcommand\pdd[2]{\frac{\partial#1}{\partial#2}}
\newcommand\pddd[2]{\frac{\partial^2#1}{\partial#2^2}}
\newcommand\cc{\mathrm c . \mathrm c .}
\newcommand\hc{\mathrm h . \mathrm c .}
\newcommand\myvec[2]{\left(\begin{array}{c}#1\\#2\end{array}\right)}
\newcommand\mymat[4]{\left(\begin{array}{cc} #1 & #2\\ #3 & #4\end{array} \right)}
\newcommand\sign{\operatorname{sign}}
\newcommand\Cin{\operatorname{Cin}}

\begin{document}
```

And the compiler:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.3-1.40.12 (TeX Live 2011)
```

Comment: And what is the content after `\begin{document}`? Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: There is 500 lines of code after `\begin{document}`, but I'll try to produce a MWE.

Comment: Basically it can't happen, but if it does happen and you get the bad fonts check what fonts it is (either using the acrobat reader fonts menu or pdffonts command line utility. If you know what fonts are being used it's a lot easier to trace where they came from. (assuming those fonts really are in the pdf file and it isn't some viewer glitch)

Comment: Do you use the same viewer all the time?

Comment: Could the pdf reader be in cause ? Does it automatically refresh your document ? Did you try to close and re-open it, for instance with another reader (for some good pdfreaders, [http://pdfreaders.org/](http://pdfreaders.org/)).

Comment: Have you tested with different PDF viewers? I sometimes see something similar with my PDF viewer (Evince on Linux), when it is reloading the PDF before the PDF is fully written to disk. Test in more viewers to make sure it is not a viewer problem

Comment: @daleif : same idea, 3 seconds of difference between our comments !

Comment: @Clément I am using the reader inside TeXShop (v 2.47). I tried to open a *anormal* file with another pdf reader and it shows a proper output. In conclusion, it is the viewer of TeXShop that has issues.

Comment: @Clément, I know, saw the two comments being added while writing.

Comment: @ChocoPouce, I'd recommend always test in Adobe Reader when in doubt. Many PDF viewers have small rare case kinks. AR is (or ought to be) the definitive benchmark.

Comment: My advice would be to update your TeXShop: many features have been added, many bug fixed, since the version you have installed.
Notably, the previewer has been enhanced. [See the changelog](http://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/texshop/changes_3.html): the latest version is 3.36.2 !

Comment: This is rather a comment than an answer.

Comment: @ChocoPouce Sometimes the font cache gets corrupted.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer : you are probably right, but it still _is_ a solution, isnt'it?

Comment: Could you test it thoroughly? `;-)`

Comment: The fact is I can't, because my distribution is to old (OSX 10.5.8)

Comment: Is there an option to "refresh" the pdf displayed in the viewer without re-compiling the source code? You seems to say that it "sometimes works, sometimes does not".

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a problem due to font cache corruption (printing characters in Helvetica is a clear sign of this) which does not depend on TeX and friends.